# select the next data in query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you please help me. I'm trying to get the records per day and also the fist record of the next day(2013-08-31).

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE `number` = 'ABC123' AND `date`='2013-08-30');
```

Comment: First by what criteria?

Answer (score 0):

This will get the first record of the next day:

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicle
WHERE number = 'ABC123' AND date = '2013-08-31'
ORDER by <some column>
LIMIT 1
```

If you want both results in a single query, connect them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM vehicle
      WHERE number = 'ABC123' AND date = '2013-08-31'
      ORDER BY <some column>
      LIMIT 1) AS next_day
UNION ALL
     (SELECT *
      FROM vehicle
      WHERE number = 'ABC123' AND date = '2013-08-30'
     ) AS first_day
```

Comment: if i use union and i limit it to 1 only one records well be show. i want the all records of the  2013-08-30 and also the first record in the next day. in just one query. thank for the reply!

Comment: You can put the LIMIT clause on just one of the queries in the UNION. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**fist record**, needs a column that contain a number or date which can we find the `MAX()` or something else to ordering it.

So in your case, I assume you have a column `vehicle_id` with integer type data and *autonumber*.

So your query is :

`SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE date = '2013-08-30' ORDER BY vehicle_id DESC LIMIT 1`

And you'll get wat you want

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle
WHERE
   number = 'ABC123'
   AND date = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
   AND date = '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 days"))."'";
```

This will return both date which your current date and next date suppose your current date is `'2013-08-30'` and next date `'2013-08-31'`

Comment: no sir i just want to get the record in particular day for example 2013-08-30 that day. lets say that there are 10 records or more in that day then i want to get ALSO the first record in the next day. In just one query? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and it's work but slow response.

`(SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE`number`= 'ABC123' AND`date`='2013-08-30' ORDER by date asc)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE`number`= 'ABC123' AND`date`='2013-08-30' ORDER by date asc limit 1);`

can any one have a better one? thank!